# Can't remove extra top space over body

Tags: html, css

I'm making a very basic website, but can't remove the extra top space over the body element. It looks like this in both Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

I've tried most relevant solutions I found on this forum: I reset my body and HTML margin and padding to 0. Also, I made sure there are no children elements with top margins messing with my code.

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.navbar {
 background:#312c2a;
 height: 30px;
 text-align:center;
}

.navbar li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right:20px;
 margin-left:20px;
}

.navbar a {
 color: white;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is my HTML code. I really can't find any problem. Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Poesía en traducción</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imgs/favicon.png"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>

<body> 

 <div class="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="about.html">quiénes somos</a></li>
   <li><a href="autores.html">autores</a></li>
   <li><a href="poemas.html">poemas</a></li>
   <li><a href="servicios.html">servicios de traducción</a></li>
   <li><a href="contacto.html">contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="portada">

 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many browsers give unordered lists a default top and bottom margin. You should add:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```css
body,
html,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: #312c2a;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Poesía en traducción</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imgs/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">quiénes somos</a></li>
      <li><a href="autores.html">autores</a></li>
      <li><a href="poemas.html">poemas</a></li>
      <li><a href="servicios.html">servicios de traducción</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacto.html">contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="portada">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
.navbar {
     width: 100%;
     height: 70px;
     background: black;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     position: fixed; /*fixed, relative, or absolute like you want*/
     top: 0px;
     z-index: 200;
}



ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

and

```
.body{
    margin: 0;              
    padding: 0;
    background-color:white;
}
```